# Does anyone know what this message means

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

2017-09-20 08:15:20.616 3740    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1402734 (99.8%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 22h 47m 33s

My monero wallet has already sync, but I logged on today and it keeps trying to sync again, the number of blocks remaining keeps going up slightly and it is only at 2733 but it does not seem to be syncing properly and I cant get an accurate wallet ballance

Answer (score 3):

You are stuck at the height of the [most recent fork](https://getmonero.org/2017/09/13/september-15-2017-protocol-upgrade-hard-fork.html).  It appears you have not upgraded to v.0.11.0.0 or after.  Please download new binaries from https://getmonero.org/downloads/.

Comment: When did Monero go through a fork?

Comment: The fork was activated on block 1400000, which was mined on Sep 16, 2017